# Data Model for Profile Page Views

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

Say I have a site with user profiles that have publicly accessible pages (each profile has several pages each). I'd like to show the users page view statistics (e.g. per page, for a certain time period, etc.). What's a good way to store page views?

Here's what I was thinking:

```
Table Page Views
================
- Id (PK)
- Profile Id (FK)
- Page Id (FK)
- Timestamp
```

I'm afraid this solution won't scale. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, writing to a database doesn't scale particularly well. You want to avoid a database transaction for each page request.

That noted, is scaling really your concern? If so, and assuming a Internet site (as opposed to intra), skip rolling your own and collect the hit data with Google Analytics or something similar. Then take that data and process it to generate totals per profile.

However, if you're really hellbent on doing it yourself, consider log parsing instead. If you can enumerate the URLs per profile, use that information, and your web server logs, to generate hit totals. Tools such as [Microsoft's Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en), which can process A LOT of different formats, or *nix command line tools like sed and grep are your friends here.

If enumeration's not possible change code to log the information you need and process that log file.

With logs in place, generate results using a batch process and insert those results into a database using MySQL's [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

Final note on the roll your own approach I've recommended - this will scale *a lot* better if you have a clustered environment than database transaction per request.

Comment: Using Google Analytics didn't occur to me. Does it expose an API I can use to query (I assume by URL, which means I need to design my URLs a certain way). Also, this is a LAMP application, how do I access Apache logs for reporting purposes?

Comment: Google Analytics has an API for exporting data: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/ you would be getting data from it per URL. Apache Log location depends on *nix version: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-logs/ I would use whatever application server you've got to shell out to grep and parse the logs then run it through sed to get the values you need.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of reports you want to make available.

If you want to be able to say "this is the list of people that viewed your page between these two dates", then you must store all the data you proposed.

If you only need to be able to say "your page was viewed X times between these two dates", then you only need a table with a page ID, date, and counter. Update the counter column on each page view with a single UPDATE query.

Comment: right now, I think I only need #2 scenario. How would you model for such a scenario?

Comment: UPDATE profile_views SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE page_id = X and date = CURRENT_DATE

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can have

**tblPerson**

```
personid(pk)
activeProfileID(fk)    -- the active profile to use.
timestamp
```

**tblPage**

```
pageid(pk)
data
```

**tblPersonProfile**

```
profileID(pk)
timestamp
```

**tblProfilePages**

```
profilePageID(pk)
profileid(pk)
pageid(pk)
isActive
```

Comment: are multiple tables a good idea for this? Wouldn't a single table be better?